# Selenium XPath finding gif to click

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, gif

I am having trouble with clicking all buttons that are defined as animation format (.gif) on a website. I use XPath in Selenium to find these buttons with their ids but the script doesn't continue at this line. How can I click all these buttons by finding all gifs?

My script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'D:\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("http://svtbilgi.dsi.gov.tr/Sorgu.aspx")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_hld1_cbHavza").click()
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_hld1_cbHavza")).select_by_visible_text("15. Kizilirmak Havzasi")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_hld1_btnListele").click()
parent_handle = driver.current_window_handle
all_urls = []
all_images = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id,'OL_Icon')]/img")
for image in all_images :
     image.click()
     for handle in driver.window_handles :
          if handle != parent_handle:
              driver.switch_to_window(handle)
              WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
              all_urls.append(driver.current_url)
              driver.close()
              driver.switchTo.window(parent_handle)
```

Comment: why are you clicking again on drop down after selecting `15. Kizilirmak Havzasi` from drop down ?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I deleted it. But how about my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues. First you need to wait for the images load. Second, for some reason, the normal selenium `click()` method doesn't seem to work.  Instead you can use an action chain to perform the click. The following worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'D:\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("http://svtbilgi.dsi.gov.tr/Sorgu.aspx")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_hld1_cbHavza").click()
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_hld1_cbHavza")).select_by_visible_text("15. Kizilirmak Havzasi")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_hld1_btnListele").click()
parent_handle = driver.current_window_handle
all_urls = []

try:
    # Wait for images to load
    xpath = "//div[contains(@id,'OL_Icon')]/img"
    condition = EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath))
    all_images = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(condition)

except (TimeoutException, Exception):
    print('No images loaded.')
    all_images = []

for image in all_images:

    # Click image using action chain
    action = webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element_with_offset(image, 5, 5)
    action.click()
    action.perform()

    for handle in driver.window_handles:
        if handle != parent_handle:
            driver.switch_to_window(handle)
            WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
            all_urls.append(driver.current_url)
            driver.close()
            driver.switchTo.window(parent_handle)

            # Depending on your version of selenium, you may need this syntax:
            # driver.switch_to_window(parent_handle)
```

It may be the case, that you just need to offset where you are trying to click the image, which an action chain will allow.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it stops after one website is opened. How can that problem solved?

Comment: I couldn't see your comment, I'm sorry, I just changed 'driver.switchTo.window(parent_handle)' to 'driver.switch_to_window(parent_handle)', thank you again.

Comment: Also, added 'from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException'

Comment: Thank you for catching that! I updated the answer for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I got it working through [ActionChains](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) class -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\Test automation\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://svtbilgi.dsi.gov.tr/Sorgu.aspx")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_hld1_cbHavza").click()
Select(driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_hld1_cbHavza")).select_by_visible_text("15. Kizilirmak Havzasi")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_hld1_btnListele").click()
parent_handle = driver.current_window_handle
driver.maximize_window()
all_urls = []
all_images = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@id,'OL_Icon')]/img")))
print len(all_images)
for image in all_images :
     webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(image).click(image).perform()
     for handle in driver.window_handles :
          if handle != parent_handle:
              driver.switch_to_window(handle)
              WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
              all_urls.append(driver.current_url)
              driver.close()
              driver.switch_to.window(parent_handle)

print all_urls
```

Comment: I realized that that can't extract all webpages, that also extracts some websites one, two or more times again. How can you address this issue? Thanks, again.